# Why is redeclaring a template member function allowed in C++?

Tags: c++

```
class test{
 public:
 int call();
};

int test::call();

int main(){return 0;}
```

The above will not compile, with this error:

```
error: declaration of 'int test::call()' outside of class is not definition
```

However, the same code is allowed if templates are used as such:

```
class test{
 public:
 template<class T>
 int call();
};

template int test::call<int>(); // what's the point of this line?

template <class T>
int test::call(){
  T in = 5;
  return in;
}

int main(){
 test t;
 
 return 0;
}
```

I have 2 questions on this:

1- What's the point of the re-declaration? I have seen similar code in other projects.

2- Why does it compile and my first code snippet won't?

Comment: It's not a declaration: Note that it actually specifies `int`. It's an "instantiation".

Comment: Why would that matter? It's also not a definition so what is the state of it?

Comment: Someone can correct me if I am wrong but doesn't this force `int test::call<int>()` to be generated whether the compiler finds use or not? Yeah as far as I can see it forces it to be generated, after running a simple POC

Comment: @Lala5th - only if it was after the out of line definition. As it were it just instantiates a declaration.

Comment: This is called explicit template instantiaton. You can look this up.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica are you sure about it?

Comment: @SergeyA - Top to bottom parsing, always. Can't instantiate what wasn't seen.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica but it does in my tests... Do you have a link to relevant documentation?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I ran a sample code through objdump and `test<int>` was generated (or rather: `_Z5testIiEvT_`, which is the same), even though it was before definition. Using `g++ 10.3`. This might be a standard extension though

Comment: @SergeyA - But not in the OP's, since they report no error. Then again, I can see the OP's test, not yours.

Comment: I misunderstood the question and take half the blame. Maybe [edit] your question to include an actual definition of `test::call` in your first snippet so the only difference in the two is the "templatisation" of `call`.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Why would there be an error? Using OP's code verbatim I end up with function being generated.

Comment: @Lala5th - `test<int>` is not in the OP in any fashion. And again, I can't comment on what I don't see.

Comment: @Lala5th I concur with your finding and waiting for Story Teller to explain.

Comment: @SergeyA - The OP compares two code pieces. One produces an error. Ergo, the error is pertinent... that is, assuming they had a member function definition there, and not just an ill-formed construct.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I didn't use the class around it, but the order of declarations/definitions are the same. You can run a test but you fail to provide the part of the standard that this violates apparently.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica here is the godbolt link: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/6aPsvs8jx in this snippet the template is instantiated before it is defined, yet the function is generated.

Comment: @Lala5th - Convinetly there is also no wording that says *it should* instsntiate the definition. Feel free to check yourself https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.explicit

Comment: Ugh.... https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.point#7.sentence-1 - the extra point of instantiation at the end of the TU. Whether or not it trips nasal demons with this https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.point#7.sentence-4 seems a subject to debate. But it's 1:30 am here, so I will not be participating.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template states that "Only the declaration is required [...] when explicitly instantiating a function template, a variable template, a member function or static data member of a class template, or a member function template.", which is implied in the standard with: "A definition of a class template, a member class of a class template, or a member class template of a class or class template shall precede an explicit instantiation of that entity....".

Comment: I agree with StoryTeller... the explicit instantiation itself is a point of definition (paragraph 5) and the end of the TU is a point of definition, and different specializations are in scope ergo ill-formed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not a declaration, but a definition. This is called an [explicit template instantiation of a function template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template#Function_template_instantiation).

This forces the compiler to instantiate the `int` version in your case. You could also add explicit instantiation for many types:

```
class test{
 public:
 template<class T>
 int call() { return 0; }
};

template int test::call<int>();
template int test::call<float>();
```

It is useful to make compilation faster or control visibility of instantiation requirements by controlling when instantiation happen. This is often coupled with the `extern template` feature:

```
// ------------------
// ----- test.h -----
// ------------------
class test{
 public:
 template<class T>
 int call();
};

// Here, we tell the compiler that the instantiation exists somewhere
// That somewhere may not visible, so the compiler won't try to instantiate it
extern template int test::call<int>();
extern template int test::call<float>();


// ------------------
// ---- test.cpp ----
// ------------------

#include "test.h"

// define the template in the cpp only
template <class T>
int test::call(){
  T in = 5;
  return in;
}

// provide definitions for the instantiations:
template int test::call<int>();
template int test::call<float>();
```